# Ports needed for the vSphere 5.5 client to connect to the vCenter

Tags: port, vmware-vsphere, vmware-vcenter

We are currently setting up a new vmware environement based on ESXi 5.5, with the virtual appliance and vSphere client. After a lot of research (maybe I didn't searched well), I couldn't manage to find which ports needs to be open between the vSphere client and the vCenter (to get the communication ok and the vm consoles). I found some articles but they are rather a list of all the used ports on VMWare.

Do you have any idea ? Thanks in advance,

Comment: You're google-foo is poor, we expect SF users to be able to find this kind of basic information before coming here, please consider this in any future questions.

Comment: This question kind of makes me angry, because it took me all of 30 seconds to find the answer in the vSphere 5.5 documentation, which is readily available to anyone with an internet connection (which you obviously have).

Comment: If you had read my complete question you would have saw this at the end: "I found some articles but they are rather a list of all the used ports on VMWare.". Meaning: I found the documentation but it lists all the ports used by VMWare while I was only interessed in the ports used between vSphere and the vCenter appliance. The official table from VMWare doesn't clearly state if a port is used for vCenter <-> vSphere communication or for ESXi host <-> vCenter communication, thus my question!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This looks like the doc you need.  Start at page 130
http://pubs.vmware.com/vsphere-55/topic/com.vmware.ICbase/PDF/vsphere-esxi-vcenter-server-55-security-guide.pdf

Looks like mostly TCP 443, 9443, 9090, 902 but there is a whole table on pg 132

I think this is the part you were asking about:

**Connecting Through vCenter Server with the vSphere Client**

When you are connecting with the vSphere Client, the required ports depend on whether you connect directly to the ESXi host or you connect to a vCenter Server system.

**Port 443**

Port 443 connects clients such as the vSphere Web Services SDK to ESXi
through the Tomcat Web service or the SDK. The host process multiplexes
port 443 data to the appropriate recipient for processing.
When the vSphere SDK is connected directly to ESXi, it can use this port to
support any management functions related to the host and its virtual
machines. Port 443 is the port that clients such as the vSphere SDK assume is
available when sending data to ESXi. VMware does not support configuring
a different port for these connections.

**Port 902**

This is the port that vCenter Server assumes is available for receiving data
from ESXi.
Port 902 connects vCenter Server to the host through the VMware
Authorization Daemon (vmware-authd). This daemon multiplexes port 902
data to the appropriate recipient for processing. VMware does not support
configuring a different port for this connection

**Connecting Directly with the vSphere Client**

With the vSphere Client, you can connect directly to an ESXi host.

**Port 902**

The vSphere Client uses this port to provide a connection for guest operating
system MKS activities on virtual machines. It is through this port that users
interact with the guest operating systems and applications of the virtual
machine. VM